# Accessibility of inner class

Tags: c++, class, oop

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 
 
template <class T, class U>
class Enclosing {       
    private:    
       int x; 
    public:
    class Nested;

    Nested setnested (int x){
        Enclosing::Nested* temp;
        temp->A->x=5;
        return *temp;
    }

    class Nested { 
        Enclosing *A  ;  
        void NestedFun() { 
        cout<<this->A->x;   
        }        
    }; 
};


  
int main() 
{      
  return 0;
}
```

This code runs well but if I eliminate template sign of class Enclosing, errors appear.

```
'Enclosing* Enclosing::Nested::A' is private within this context.
```

How to override Nested `setnested(int x)` outside the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This code runs well but if I eliminate template sign of class Enclosing, errors appear.

Actually, the same error applies to the template version, it's just that the access specifier of `A` is not checked until `setnested` is instantiated.

If you add these lines to `main`:

```
Enclosing<int,int> e;
e.setnested(42);
```

you get the same [error](https://godbolt.org/z/K7bcvK).

---

One way to fix this is to make `Enclosing` a friend of `Nested`, like this:

```
class Nested { 
    friend class Enclosing;  
    // ...
};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YM7so3).

---

> How to override Nested setnested(int x) outside the class?

```
template <class T, class U>
auto Enclosing<T, U>::setnested(int x) -> Nested {
    Enclosing::Nested* temp;
    temp->A->x=5;
    return *temp;
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6zbzof).